# form submit (get request) on html goes to blank page and nothing logs when console.log in node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a html page that I have been trying to get to work for the longest. It is a form with 2 text boxes that takes a string each. I am trying to get the values from the 2 text boxes and send them to the server. However, whenever I try to submit the form, it automatically changes to a blank page. Because of this it seems that the action doesn't even go through. I have made console.log messages to check if it even reaches my server and it doesn't.

This is my html code

```
<html>
 <body onecontextmenu="return false">
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="grad"></div>
  <div class="header">
     <div>Log<span>In</span></div>
  </div>
   <br>
   <form name="data" action = '127.0.0.1:8080/youraction' method="get">
      <div class="data">
         <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="email"><br>
         <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="fname"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
      </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this is my node js code for the get method.

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http = require('http');
var q = require('q');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:PORT/DBNAME";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

app.get('/youraction', function(req, res){
 client.connect();
 text = "SELECT email,firstname FROM customer WHERE customer.email = $1 AND 
  customer.firstname = $2";
 values = [req.body.email, req.body.fname];
 client.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
       console.log (err.stack)
    } else{
       console.log(res.rows)
    }
 });
```

Because the html seems to go straight to a blank page, I can't capture the text field data.

Comment: On what port does your server listen? 8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `method="get"`, you retrieve the fields using `req.query`.

You're using `req.body` to retrieve the form field values, but this would only work if you changed the form method to `method="post"`.

To get things working, change this line:

`values = [req.body.email, req.body.fname];`

to:

`values = [req.query.email, req.query.fname];`

Comment: Thanks I ended up making it a post.